# How would I modify this to put it into a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
question_prompts = [
    "What color are Apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
    "What color are Bananas?\n(a) Blue\n(b) Yellow\n(c) Green\n\n",
    "What color are Strawberries?\n(a) Red\n(b) Blue\n(c) Green\n\n" ]

def main_questions():
```

These are a set of three questions, and they have three answers which I didn't post. I'm trying to figure out how I would put this in the function called main_questions():
I am a beginner, I've looked at multiple articles but can't seem to understand them. Help please?

Comment: Functions are meant to *do*and/or *return* things; what is it you want this function to *do* and/or *return*?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting it in a function?

Comment: @ScottHunter I need this function to return each one of those questions on the screen.

Comment: What does "return something on the screen" mean?  Do you mean `print`?

Comment: @bat_s08 Possibly use a loop to show the questions. You can also use a dictionary to map the answers to the questions and check if the correct answer is selected by the user.

Comment: @sks-15 Okay, I'll take a look into that and try it thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a possible solution for you. I have added several command for the better understanding. You can try the following implementation:

**Code:**

```
question_prompts = [
    "What color are Apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
    "What color are Bananas?\n(a) Blue\n(b) Yellow\n(c) Green\n\n",
    "What color are Strawberries?\n(a) Red\n(b) Blue\n(c) Green\n\n"]


def main_questions():
    answer_list = []  # This list will contain the all answers
    answer_choices = ["a", "b", "c"]  # The possible answers
    for single_question in question_prompts:
        while True:
            single_answer = input(single_question)
            if single_answer in answer_choices:  # Break the while loop if get a valid answer.
                break
            print("Your answer is not in: {}".format(answer_choices))
        answer_list.append(single_answer)  # Append the correct answer to the return list.
    return answer_list  # Return the all valid answers


answers = main_questions()
print("\nAnswers:\n")
for idx, answer in enumerate(answers):
    print("{}. - {}".format(idx, answer))
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
What color are Apples?
(a) Red/Green
(b) Purple
(c) Orange

a
What color are Bananas?
(a) Blue
(b) Yellow
(c) Green

b
What color are Strawberries?
(a) Red
(b) Blue
(c) Green

g
Your answer is not in: ['a', 'b', 'c']
What color are Strawberries?
(a) Red
(b) Blue
(c) Green

b

Answers:

0. - a
1. - b
2. - b
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the select colors, you can define a dict which contains the key-value pairs. You can use the following function for it (other parts are the same as below)

**Code:**

```
def main_questions():
    answer_list = []  # This list will contain the all answers
    answer_choices = {1: {"a": "Red/Green", "b": "Purple", "c": "Orange"},
                      2: {"a": "Blue", "b": "Yellow", "c": "Green"},
                      3: {"a": "Red", "b": "Blue", "c": "Green"}}
    answer_counter = 1
    for single_question in question_prompts:
        while True:
            single_answer = input(single_question)
            if single_answer in answer_choices[answer_counter]:  # Break the while loop if get a valid answer.
                break
            print("Your answer is not in: {}".format(answer_choices[answer_counter]))
        answer_list.append(answer_choices[answer_counter][single_answer])  # Append the correct answer to the return list.
        answer_counter += 1
    return answer_list  # Return the all valid answers
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
What color are Apples?
(a) Red/Green
(b) Purple
(c) Orange

a
What color are Bananas?
(a) Blue
(b) Yellow
(c) Green

b
What color are Strawberries?
(a) Red
(b) Blue
(c) Green

g
Your answer is not in: {'a': 'Red', 'b': 'Blue', 'c': 'Green'}
What color are Strawberries?
(a) Red
(b) Blue
(c) Green

b

Answers:

0. - Red/Green
1. - Yellow
2. - Blue
```